# Personal Relationship Managment or CRM

Tags: android, web-apps, information-management, crm, address-book

I'm looking for a personal CRM kind of system. Only usually CRM is aimed for business and sales. I just like to keep information about people in one place. For example I know people in industry that I speak from time to time and I'd like to keep some personal relevant information close at hand - like ages of kids, wife's place of work, other tidbits that you usually forget after a while.

I.e. I'm planning to call Mr Smith, so I can quickly look up personal info about Mr. Smith and ask how's his kids are getting on in school and remind myself their names and ages.

It's nice to have people remembering irrelevant information about you. I'd like to remember this kind of stuff about people I interact with.

I've tried a few CRMs but they are all business oriented. Is there anything out there that can help me?

Ideally it should work on Android and through Web, be able to hook into social media and do search by name.

P.S. It does not have to be free. I'm ready to pay a reasonable monthly fee for this service

Comment: Depending on where you live, it's not allowed to collect such data without prior agreement. As far as I know you need to protect such data and provide a Privacy Agreement.

Comment: What about using the notes field at the contacts address entry of the default addressbook?

Comment: Privacy agreement is not here nor there. Notes field is not structured. I'd like a bit more structure than just a blob of text. Relationship, dates, birthday reminders, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Zoho Contacts Manager](https://www.zoho.com/contactmanager) looks like it could fit.

As in any address book, you have structured fields, but you can also add notes for each person.

There is an Android app to sync with.

You can tag people, for instance "work" or "soccer", a person can have several tags.

It does have some business features, but it is usable by casual users too.

It boasts Social Media Integration with Facebook/Twitter, I don't know how far that goes but I guess it will not get your friends' birthdays from Facebook.

Free for up to 500 contacts, then 15 USD per month.

[image: Zoho Contacts Manager person details]

Comment: Looks interesting, I'll have a look

Answer (score 2):

## [Gramps](https://gramps-project.org)

The tool I use for a very similar use case is Gramps. It is actually genealogy software but I find that it manages personal relationships much better than any CRM.

### Features

- Desktop app on Mac, Windows and Linux
- Manages birthdays, anniversaries, spouses, (grand)kids, photos, notes, etc
- It is searchable
- Multiple distinct databases

#### Missing

- No web interface
- No Android app
- No social media integration

[image: gramps person entry]

I love using Gramps. I have 3 data-sets; coworkers, neighborhood, and family (in-laws). For example, with my coworkers I track what I know of their parents, spouses, children and grandchildren. The family tree aspect is really awesome for that. I've added miscellaneous photos and use it to help prep my wife for company events.

Comment: Looks very interesting, but lack of web-interface is a turn-off. I have a number of places I need access to this data...

Answer (score 0):

One other solution you might want to have a look at is [Simitless](https://www.simitless.com/). Essentially, it is a platform that enables you to create you own information system/data app. A lot of people would use it for business related tasks, but the beauty of the platform is that it is fully modular. Meaning, you create your own app in accordance with what you need or what you want to track.

You add/remove the fields that are interesting for you and for your use and the platform provides these fields (like email, phone, text, picture, etc.). Once you have made the structure for your app (you can either start from scratch or get inspiration from some of the readily available templates) you can import the data (or input it manually). You can also export it if you want. It is an online platform (no need to install anything), it is searchable, it has a web interface, it has no social media integration though (so far). Have a look if you are curious.

**Full disclosure: I am part of the startup that designed that platform.** We just launched recently, still in beta. If you want to try it out and need some help, I can definitely give you a hand. Just get in touch. (If you want to quickly try it out, there is a template for personal relationship management that I have made from what you have described that you would like to track, it is viewable right [here](https://simitless.com/en/a/templates-personal-relationship-manageme). Click the "eye" icon to preview the template with "dummy data". And, since it is just a template, you can take it as a basis and modify it to your heart's desire.) It might be just what you are looking for. And let me know how it goes, if you decide to give it a go.

[image]

Comment: Could you please describe the steps required to quickly search for a person by name, from an empty browser window?

Comment: Once your app is created, simply go to your app directly (use the URL that is assigned to your app when you build it), click the "+" next to "Filter by", select "Name" and type the name (or part of a name) of the person you want to find to see instant results.