# Open Source and Offline Personal CRM

Tags: open-source, offline, desktop-client, crm

Wanting to create, maintain and grow my network, I started looking for a `Personal CRM`, from now one I'll call it `PRM`.

One of the first results was [Monica](https://www.monicahq.com/). I like the interface and the main functionalities that I'm looking for is **contact management**, **relationship management** and **automatic reminders** (such as "You haven't contacted John in a long time, ask him about what is going with his life!"). I dislike that if one wants to be in control of all aspects of the database, it is needed to host [Monica](https://www.monicahq.com/) on your own server.

Not wanting to host a server (even in my own network) I looked around but was not able to find an offline program that satisfied the above functionalities.

My question here would be if there is any (preferably open source) offline (an application/program) `PRM`? Something like `KeePass` in the realm of password managers?

*Note*

[This answer](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/42527) suggests the use of a program called [Gramps](https://github.com/gramps-project/gramps), but technically it is not a `PRM`.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to the forum. Please can you add what you do not like about Monica to the question, or what specific functionality you are looking for? By the way, Monica also has a hosted solution - the free hosted one is restricted though.